# Does events like onClick in React pollute memory heap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was learning React and came across events like onCLick. Before that, I read an article saying that if we use addEventListener in pure JS then it can pollute memory heap thus we need to use removeEventListener() to ensure that there is no memory heap pollution. The question is "Is it the case with React?", that is, when we use onCLick or any other event in React, will any of them pollute the memory heap?

Comment: Did you try adding event listener in react?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If you do not remove event listeners, they will keep listening.
A good place to add/remove them is componentDidMount / componentWillUnmount.

Comment: And alternatively if you are solely using hooks you can cleanup in the return statement.

Comment: @Jacob, you mean even if we use React's native events like onClick, it pollutes the memory heap. Right? if so, how can we remove it then?:)

Comment: For built-in events, like component onClick. The event listener will automatically be removed when its corresponding component unmounts. However as it is still common to use addEventListener in react, and you mentioned "any other event" I was assuming you were including all event listeners. In which case you need to manually remove them.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is "Is it the case with React?", that is, when we use onCLick or any other event in React, will any of them pollute the memory heap?

No. If you use react's normal technique for event listeners, such as the onClick prop of a div, then react will cleanup those listeners for you when
the component unmounts.

For example, the following code will not cause a memory leak.

```
const ExampleComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div onClick={() => console.log('hi')}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: That is correct, however, in the op's questions there is "or any other event in React". If you were to use addEventListener in react, you will still need to clean it up your self.

Comment: `onClick or any other event in React` i took that to mean "onClick" is one example, and things like "onMouseOver", "onChange", etc would be "other events in react". addEventListener is not an event in react. And given the response the op gave to your question, where they reiterate that they care about React's `onClick`, that seems to be what they meant.

Comment: If I use addEventListener then on unmount of the component will I need to clean that?

Comment: @SurajJain yes.

Comment: Suppose I added a event listener on div present in ExampleComponent using `addEventListener`, if now some parent component state changes such that it is no longer rendering `ExampleComponent`, react will remove that ExampleComponent child DOM elements. If DOM element is removed then event listener we added on div is automatically removed, then why do we need to remove it in unmounting phase?

Comment: `If DOM element is removed then event listener we added on div is automatically removed` That isn't true. Removing an element from the DOM will not cause its listeners to be torn down. And if there are still any references to the element, that element will continue to exist in memory, detached from the document.